# VB.net application using reader HasRows

Tags: vb.net

I am running an SQL Query with data readers in vb.net

```
reader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader
reader3.Read()
If reader3.HasRows Then
    FromToDates = reader3.GetString(3)
End If
```

There are no rows being returned in this particular query, however even though the if `reader3.HasRows` is being used its still showing an error saying:

```
Additional information: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

this is when trying to set the `FromToDates` variable but there are no rows being returned so it should not even reach this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there are no rows, i assume that there is at least one row where the value is `NULL`. You could check it with the [`IsDBNull`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
If reader3.HasRows AndAlso Not reader3.IsDbNull(3)  Then
    FromToDates = reader3.GetString(3)
End If
```

However, the variable name suggests that it's a date, but you are storing it as string. Use the correct type which is `date` or `datetime`. If it's actually a `datetime` use:

```
Dim FromToDates As Date 
If reader3.HasRows AndAlso Not reader3.IsDbNull(3)  Then
    FromToDates = reader3.GetDateTime(3)
End If
```

Comment: i am using Dim FromToDates as DateTime so its setting this var as a datetime variable

Comment: @Charles: then you should set `Option Strict` to `On` and learn to use the correct types in the first place ;)

Comment: @Charles: i have edited my answer, use `reader.GetDateTime` and a `Date` variable.

Comment: still getting the same error, i want to see if rows are returned. i dont want to see if a column is null (DBNull)

Comment: @Charles: you can use `HasRows` to check if there are rows and `IsDbNull` to check if the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Reader.read() then i don't think so you need reader,hasrow(). you can do somthing like this

```
reader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader
If reader3.Read()Then
FromToDates = reader3.GetString(3)
End If
```

and related to your error its look like you are getting NULL value from database and in vb you can not read NULL, i will suggest to use ISNULL(Column_NAME,'') function in your SQL Script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even though the row is empty (all DBNull, perhaps), there IS a row object returning from the query.  There are several different solutions presented in this thread that all take differing approaches to catching the empty row before it errors!

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?555183-datareader-and-empty-records